# make div float up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a chat option for users however I only want the chat to show for a certain amount of time, I could do this via PHP and timestamp but I would also like to visually hide it by making the div containing the message to float up until it becomes hidden as an overflow..

I seen a script on the following page:
http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/scripts/bg/float_up.html
It uses images but I'd like to do the same idea with submitted messages (floating chat)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What have your tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Well I tried PHP with the time for movement but I couldn't show an easy transition and reloading the div with an ajax page request too often will put pressure on the server if too many people use it.. I haven't tried the script in the URL stated above as I am not sure how I would tell it to move the div (unless the floatr[0] lets me state it by class instead of a url) other than this I don't really know what other way to do it..

Answer (score 3):

i dont know if this is what you are trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/LPc2z/3/ ?

its kept simple because i dont know exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: +1 because I immediatly wanted to change the numbers to "rain" and give them a blue background to have an inverse storm :)

Comment: That is the most fun fiddle I've seen here today. And probably in a long time :)

Comment: its just a quick mock up, and i think there is some things to change if you'r thinking of using it for something  :).. like removing the element when it has reached the top (instead of hiding it)